# Probability of duration conditional on Poisson rate

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let there be some initial stock (continuum) of naked people $n$. Clothes arrive at rate $\lambda$. At the same time, there is an inflow of naked people at the same rate - such that we have $\dot n = 0$.

Denote the length at which a person was naked $d$. How can I compute $Prob(d \in (a, b])$?

I'm familiar with the Poisson distribution, and have read into Poisson point processes. From there, I get that the probability of an event arriving at rate $\lambda$ not happening between $(a, b]$ is given by $\exp(-\lambda(b - a))$. How do I go on from here? This probability is naturally the same, independent of waiting duration - I'd need to compute the implied distribution over duration, and then divide measure of people at some interval over the total mass?

Comment: Are people bothered by me using unconventional variables and states to move? I thought having some nakedness might lighten things up, but I can remove the graphics from the problem.

Comment: To be honest I have never seen the $\dot n$ notation, so yeah you might want to explicit this.  Also, you don't explain how the clothes are associated with the naked people, so your problem does not have one answer. To whom a new cloth coming will be given ? Can someone have several clothes?  I believe this messy formulation is offputting, but because it is tough to understand, not because of the nakedness.